# Trouble installing mergMicrophone from mergext

Tags: xcode, installation, mergmicrophone

I am getting an error when running mergMicrophone's sample code.

I have installed Xcode and added the mergMicrophone library to LiveCode under StandAlone->Copy_Files, but when I run the demo app by clicking the "Start" button in LiveCode, I get an error about the "Handler: can't find Handler near mergMicrophoneStartRecording".

I would think this means I don't have the mergMicrophone library installed, but I think I have followed the install correctly, and honestly, it's pretty simple.

I have stop/started Xcode and LiveCode a few times, but with no luck.

I am new to LiveCode and mergMicrophone, so I might be doing something wrong that's quite simple.

TIA,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Is mergMicrophone for OSX or iOS?

Usually, to make an external visible to LiveCode, you need to set the external property of the mainstack of your project. A relative path like "externals/mergMicrophone.bundle" should be sufficient, but it is often tricky to get it to work. It might be more effective to set the externals property to an absolute file path, like below.

Note that the external property needs to be set before you open the stack. E.g.

```
set the itemDel to slash
put item 1 to -2 of the effective filepath of stack myStack & \
  "/externals/mergMicrophone" into myPath
go to stack "Placeholder"
set the externals of stack "Placeholder" to myPath
start using stack "Placeholder"
```

won´t work but

```
set the itemDel to slash
put item 1 to -2 of the effective filepath of stack myStack & \
  "/externals/mergMicrophone" into myPath
set the externals of stack "Placeholder" to myPath
go inv stack "Placeholder"
start using stack "Placeholder"
```

just might work.

On iOS, I would try to figure out what the absolute file path should be and use that. Don't try to use a trick like the above, because you can't open 2 stacks at the same time (but you might put 2 stacks in use at the same time).